# Can't figure out 404 error in Expressjs related to route

Tags: express

I think I'm missing something simple but I can't figure out why I can't navigate to the login page.
Views:

index:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  a(href="/login.html") Login
```

login:

```
extends layout 

block content 
    form(action="post")
        input(type="text")  
        input(type="password")
        input(type="submit", value="Login")
```

Login router:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    
    router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('login');
    });
    
    module.exports = router;
```

app.js:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var loginRouter = require('./routes/login');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/login',loginRouter)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
NotFoundError: Not Found
    at C:\Users\alexi\VS code projects\ideology-project\server\app.js:27:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\alexi\VS code projects\ideology-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\alexi\VS code projects\ideology-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\alexi\VS code projects\ideology-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\alexi\VS code projects\ideology-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\alexi\VS code projects\ideology-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at C:\Users\alexi\VS code projects\ideology-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:646:15
    at next (C:\Users\alexi\VS code projects\ideology-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:265:14)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\alexi\VS code projects\ideology-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
    at router (C:\Users\alexi\VS code projects\ideology-project\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

Comment: `a(href="/login.html")` so it would be `router.get('/login.html',` then you need a handler for `form(action="post")` i.e `router.post('/login.html',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. I put '/login' in the login router, while it must be '/' instead:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router()

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login');
  });
  
  module.exports = router;
```